# How to wrap a function from a different namespace while keeping the function name?

Tags: python, wrapper

I want to wrap a function with `timeit_wrapper` like this:

```
import timeit_wrapper

def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    func1 = timeit_wrapper(func1)
    func1()
```

The above will result in an *referenced before assignment* error since func1 is assigned to in a local scope.

How can I achieve this in a pythonic way (without the global keyword)?

Comment: How about `wrapped_func1 = timeit_wrapper(func1)` and `wrapped_func1()`?

Comment: I want it to still be called func1 (get_batch in reality) to make the code easier to understand and easier to change - is it possible?

Comment: Wow.  2 seconds to answer my question ;-)  You're fast.  Then what do you do not like about the `global` keyword?  That would solve your issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LearnOPhile no. In theory you could use `timeit_wrapper(globals()['func1'])` but that is something you should be ashamed of.

Comment: The global keyword will change the global variable func1 (wrap it with timeit_wrapper) - which I do not want.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
import timeit_wrapper

def func1():
    pass

def func2(func1=func1):
    func1 = timeit_wrapper(func1)
    func1()
```